# How to make an entity move back and forth on its own?

Tags: swiftui, realitykit, visionos

I have a sphere that I want to move consistently along the axis. With this code I would expect it to move infinitely to the right. It isn't moving at all.

```
var body: some View {
      RealityView { content in
            do {
                let immersiveEntity = try await Entity(named: "Immersive", in: realityKitContentBundle)
                immersiveEntity.name = "sphere"
                content.add(immersiveEntity)
            } catch {
                
            }
        } update: { content in
            guard let sphere = content.entities.first(where: { entity in
                entity.name == "sphere"
            }) else { return }
            sphere.position.x += 0.1
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

To implement your idea you'll need a little trick:

```
import SwiftUI
import RealityKit

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var forward: Float = 0.1
    let backward: Float = -0.1
    let cube = ModelEntity(mesh: .generateBox(size: 0.1))
    
    func backAndForth() {
        if cube.position.x >= 0 && cube.position.x <= 0.5 {
            cube.position.x += forward                
        } else if cube.position.x > 0.5 {
            forward = backward
            cube.position.x += backward               
        } else if cube.position.x < 0 {
            forward = 0.1
            cube.position.x += forward
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        RealityView { content in
            cube.position.z = -3.0
            content.add(cube)
        }
        .onAppear {
            Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.3, repeats: true) { _ in
                Task {
                    backAndForth()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Update isn't being triggered by your current code, you want to make changes.

`update` requires that SwiftUI tells it when to redraw. You can do this with any of the compatible `propertyWrapper`s or `macro`s

```
import SwiftUI
import RealityKit
struct VariablePositionSample: View {
    //Property wrapper that can signal a redraw.
    @State private var xPosition: Float = 0
    let name: String = "earth"
    var body: some View {
        RealityView { content in
            do {
                let immersiveEntity = try await Entity(named: "Earth")
                immersiveEntity.name = name
                content.add(immersiveEntity)
                //Give position and initial value
                xPosition = immersiveEntity.position.x
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        } update: { content in
            guard let sphere = content.entities.first(where: { entity in
                entity.name == name
            }) else { return }
            //Set the new position
            sphere.position.x = xPosition
        }
        .task {
            var goingUp = true
            //While the View is alive
            while true {
                print(xPosition)
                //Every second
                try? await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(1))
                //Move by 0.1 x
                if goingUp {
                    xPosition += 0.1
                } else {
                    xPosition -= 0.1
                }
                //Left/Right
                if xPosition >= 0.5 {
                    goingUp = false
                } else if xPosition <= -0.5 {
                    goingUp = true
                }
            }
            
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    VariablePositionSample()
}
```